# DiffUtil breaks contract for areContentTheSame [fix coming in next release]

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, listadapter, androidx

recently I've found strange crashes in my app. I've found out that they are caused by `ListAdapter` -> `DiffUtil` underneath. Contract says that `areContentsTheSame` callback will be called only if `areItemsTheSame` returns **true** for corresponding items. 
Problem is `areContentsTheSame` is called for items that `areItemsTheSame` was never called.

I'm testing it on `String` items so it shouldn't be related to my own recycler implementation. I'm really confused if it's my fault (there is almost no logic now) or bug in `DiffUtil` tool

I've created simple Instrumented Test that is failing on mentioned case - could someone more experienced take a look at that :

```
package com.example.diffutilbug

import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner

@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
internal class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    fun testDiffUtil4() {

        val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            throw exception
        }
        // adapter compare items :
        // areItemsTheSame -> compare length of String
        // areContentsTheSame -> compare content with ==
        val adapter = StringAdapterJunit(handler)

        runBlocking {
            adapter.submitList(
                mutableListOf<String>(
                    "1",//1,
                    "22",//2,
                    "333",//3,
                    "4444",//4,
                    "55555",//5,
                    "666666",//6,
                    "7777777",//7,
                    "88888888",//8,
                    "999999999",//9,
                    "55555",//5,
                    "1010101010",//10,
                    "1010109999",//10,
                    "55555",//5,
                    "1313131313",//10,
                    "1414141414",//10,
                    "55555",//5,
                    "1313131313",//10,
                    "1414141414",//10,
                    "55555"//5

                )
            )

            delay(40)

            adapter.submitList(
                mutableListOf<String>(
                    "55555",//5,
                    "1010101010",//10,
                    "1010109999",//10,
                    "55555",//11,
                    "1313131313",//10,
                    "1414141414",//10,
                    "11111111111"//11
                )
            )

            delay(500)
        }
    }

}

// Stub Adapter for Strings that uses DiffUtil underneath.
// logs all callbacks to logcat

class StringAdapterJunit(val handler: CoroutineExceptionHandler) : ListAdapter<String, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
        Log.e("DiffUtilTest", "areItemsTheSame comparing $oldItem with $newItem = ${oldItem.length == newItem.length}")
        return oldItem.length == newItem.length
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
        //should be called only if areContentsTheSame == true
        Log.e(
            "DiffUtilTest",
            "areContentsTheSame error = ${oldItem.length != newItem.length} comparing $oldItem with $newItem"
        )

        runBlocking {
            GlobalScope.launch(handler + Dispatchers.Main) {
                assertTrue("areContentsTheSame can be called only if areItemsTheSame return true" , areItemsTheSame(oldItem, newItem))
            }.join()
        }
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun getChangePayload(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Any? {
    //should be called only if areItemsTheSame = true and areContentsTheSame = false

        Log.e(
            "DiffUtilTest",
            "getChangePayload error = ${oldItem.length == newItem.length && oldItem == newItem} $oldItem with $newItem"
        )
        return null
    }
}) {
    // stub implementation on adapter - never used
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(View(null)) {}


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {}

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = getItem(position).length
}
```

and gradle dependencies needed for it:

```
dependencies {
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'

    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

please note that you need to add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in your `gradle.properties`

coroutines and handler for exceptions added because `DiffUtil` computes diff on background thread and `JUnit` handles assertion only on main thread

=====================================================

Fix in next alpha :
will be released in alpha 3 - PR to look after https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1253271
thanks,  can't wait to remove all workarounds!

Comment: I've created corresponding google ticket  - please up vote if you find it important to you too : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123376278

Comment: 0 - never use mutable lists in adapters, 1 - use your own adapter and provide it with your own diffutils, 2 - areItemsTheSame must compare id, be unique for item

Comment: @EvgeniiVorobei I don't use mutable list. it's problem with DiffUtil not ListAdapter as it turn out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've get respond from google and they confirm that there is bug in `DiffUtil` when lists contain duplicated items (nulls, same objects etc.)

My current workaround is to check "contract" by myself before execution so:

```
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
    return compare items
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean {
    //should be called only if areItemsTheSame == true
    return areItemsTheSame(oldItem, newItem) && compare items contents

}

override fun getChangePayload(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Any? {
    //should be called only if areItemsTheSame = true and areContentsTheSame = false
    if(areItemsTheSame(oldItem, newItem) && !areContentsTheSame(oldItem, newItem)) {
        return compute changePayload
    } else {
         return null
    }
}
```

will update answer when issue gest resolved

Comment: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/968399 PR - not submitted yet

Comment: finally fixed : https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1255508/ 
AFAIK not released yet.